# Setup attribute defined Hyperlinks in ArcGIS Online Pop-up

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-online, popup, hyperlink

I have 2 fields Asset_Name and Website. Asset Name is just a text name and Website is a URL to the website. I am trying to setup a Pop-up that has a Hyperlink where the link text is from the Asset_Name field and the URL is from the Website field. When I set it up using the GUI with `{Asset_Name}` in the Text field and `{Website}` in the URL field the Pop-up still shows the URL as the Hyperlink Text. I also tried using HTML source code `<b>Website:</b> <a href="{Website}" target="_blank">{Asset_Name}</a>` with no change in the result.
[image: The Setup in the GUI]

[image: The resulting Pop up]

This issue is some URLs are really long and make the pop-up crowded if not truncated somehow. Additionally, I would also like to find away to drop the hyperlink entirely if that specific feature doesn't have a listed website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

For a project I managed to create something like you asked on ArcGIS Online a while ago. In order to display your desired pop-up, you should combine both url + link text information in one column as an html code. ArcGIS Online will display it automatically as link text + url. For example, the html code used to get the pop up on the image was like this:

`<a href='https://www.flickr.com/photos/XXXX/XXXXX/' title='Open photo page on Flickr.'><img src='http://static.flickr.com/XXX/XXX.jpg'/></a> <p></p><p>Photo by <a href='http://www.flickr.com/people/XXX/' title='Profile on Flickr'>UrbanOccupations OETR</a>. <a href='https://www.flickr.com/photos/XXXX/XXXX/' title='Open photo page on Flickr.'>View on Flickr.</p>`

Based on this example, you can create your pop up (without showing the url) by creating a 3rd text column that combines your information in the following html format:

`<a href='HYPER LINK' title='Tooltip Text'>Link Text</a>`

You can create an additional field/column (string) in ArcGIS Online via the attribute table. Afterwards, you can use SQL or Arcade to automatize the creation of this html string using the concat() function.

Comment: I did something really similar; I built three new fields to concatenate into the link and provide text, as you suggested but instead of using Arcade or SQL I used the GUI to put them together. Because everything references fields I can actually go in a tweek each entry if I so desire using Python or SQL through AGOL or Pro. Also when using NULL it will deactivate the link for that text, it will still be blueish in colour but won't have the underline or present a click cursor.

Comment: Great to hear it worked for you! By GUI, do you mean you specified it in the Custom Attribute Display? (the area you provide in the image above?) Good to know that that is also possible, and definitely improves further tweaks later on

Comment: Yeah I did it in the Custom Attribute Display by basically assigning everything as a field variable; I just had to make more fields to hold all the info. I would have rather done something with intelligence using Arcade but I have not gotten on a course yet and I wasn't figuring it out within my time restrictions.

Comment: Whatever works, as long as it does what is required:)